# reframe iframe after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

How to refresh the iframe after ajax response success?

```
success: function (res) {       
            if (res.IsSuccess) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                $("#divLoading").hide();
                }, 2000);
                $(".modal-iframe1").attr("src", window.url.OnlineSignUrl + res.Response[0].DocumentID + "&AuthToken=" + AuthToken);
                window.location.reload();
            }else{
                alert(res.Messages);
                window.location.href='/PdfLogin.html';
            }
```

Here if i give **window.location.reload()**  it is loading the entire web page, 
Instead of loading entire web page, hoew to load iframe only?

Note: More code!
Please check the below image for more clarification [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYQa4.png)

Here several icon is there in **.pdf** search link[whereever the pdf link is there]
So if i click the first icon, i calling the iframe to load the content and signing activity [pdfimage2iframepopup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8O9S.png), once it is done i'm selecting the second image, so here the iframe is not loading it is taking the first selected image values?

Comment: If it's an actual iframe then changing the src attribute (as you do) is enough.  Simply remove the window reload.

Comment: But i'm loading the iframe inside the content script

Comment: If the iframe is part of the DOM and you change the src value then it will load that url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.reload();` will reload the entire web-page as you've already discovered.

All you need to do is change the `src` attribute of the `iframe`. That will cause it to reload.

```
$(".modal-iframe1").attr("src", window.url.OnlineSignUrl + res.Response[0].DocumentID + "&AuthToken=" + AuthToken);
```

Comment: The above iframe is only the last one, so next what will do?

Comment: what do you mean "last one" ? you don't need to do anything else. iframes will reload every time you set the `src` attribute